# Problem with a function which returns a value of two different types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I cannot understand why TypeScript cannot understand me.
I am trying to create a function, which can return a value of two different types.
Everything is explicit here, but it does not work!

```
interface IdLabel {
  id: number 
}
interface NameLabel {
  name: string 
}
type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends number
  ? IdLabel
  : NameLabel;


function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  // Throws an error!
  // Type '{ name: string; } | { id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
  return typeof idOrName === "string" ? {name: idOrName} : {id: idOrName}
}
```

But this works. I just asserted returned values

```
function createLabelFix<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  return typeof idOrName === "string" ? {name: idOrName} as NameOrId<T> : {id: idOrName} as NameOrId<T>
}
```

This is weird for me, please explain me why typescript so rude to me...

Check the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TIkC+JoksiKAcnAYRseQqXIhBEGgGcwUUAHNWHMAE8ADvykB5KBgA8AFWQQAHpBDoZtRs2QAfZHIUhFAPmQBeZCfOXrWyZoMmQAfjQsXAJQmgEhEQIAbhISAHo05AARAHsIGxAcsGQAdxyoAGsSGDoQBDBgHJBkBCgIOEhE-GNTCwgrArtoR2d5JXcACko9eOlfAEo43X10Y09xZDawOihm9S0cmAp0GalvLx8AIhclS-DiSSEaaahZtmQaIkpnk9epDg4qQyyAA6uUKjIwtVavVGs1Wu1OtF8AAxYBmHr+fqBejBFhOG5uSYvWY0IyLZCzPSGIzrUJbHZ7TQQQ7HU5Cc5XQmKO4RIiPOYk-7IOA2KkrNYfYjfNl-ITvUWU5Y09zsIA)

I do not expect any error here

Comment: As has already been mentioned, an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) is a great solution here. Also, since you're already using generics, you can get even narrower types by forwarding them to your label types: https://tsplay.dev/w84jEw

Comment: Yeah thanks, i knew about overloads. I just wanted to understand why ts does not understand such obvious moment